# How to check battery level in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to check the battery life of my phone for an app I'm writing. I'm currently trying to simply display it on the screen.
Whenever I check for the battery life, I always get the same value, which is the value at which the battery level was at when I started. If I waste battery (and I verify that a percentage point did in fact drop) during the program, the battery level which is shown will be the SAME level that was shown at the very beginning of the program.

```
// relevant class variables:
Intent batteryStatus;

Code:
//(Function that checks battery life when device is shaken:)
if(deviceShaken)
{
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
//Code to allow me to check battery life:
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Double.toString(batteryPct), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show(); //ALWAYS SHOWS THE AMOUNT OF BATTERY THAT THE PROGRAM STARTED WITH
}

onCreateMethod()
{
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
batteryStatus = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,intentFilter);
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you added broadcastreceiver in manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `batteryStatus` Intent is not updated before you retrieve the extras, so they will never change. Move the code you have in `onCreate()` to the beginning of your `if` block.